# Creating a new database for each signup, is it possible Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Currently working on a project that I don’t want to mix all users data in the same database, so I am trying to create a new **Database** upon each **Sign up**.

Thought I would be able to find such a thing online but wasn’t really able to find anything other than multi-tenant.

So the question here is:

1. Is it possible to create a new database for each user when they signup?
2. Is it going to reduce the performance of the website?
3. Would multi-tenant be a better approach to my problem?
4. Is multi-tenant a more secure approach or separated database more secure, and would I be able to edit the tables because I might need to alter the tables in the future ?

Answer (score 4):

multi-tenant solved my issue.. here is the link for the package u can use with laravel..

https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord
this package is for laravel 5.2

if u wanna know how that works in general here is the link for that
http://culttt.com/2014/03/31/multi-tenancy-laravel-4/

Comment: Hi, how did you implemented the part where you include on every request?? `Landlord::addTenant($tenantColumn, $tenantId)` 
I'm lost, and I guess it's something simple.  Thanks a lot

Comment: yea.. u can use a column called account_id for instance where each account gets an id so it will be like Landlord::addTenant('account_id', $user_id);

Comment: I know, that's not the problem, the thing is I was getting an error like: "Non-static method HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\Landlord::addTenant() should not be called statically...", so I had to inject an instance to my Middleware(or wherever I tried, like base/controller constructor), it worked, but I don't know if the injection/instantiation is obvious, or if literally the Facade is to be used.

Comment: if u r using 5.2 here is how i done it.. i added this line to the adminAuth middleware 
Landlord::addTenant('account_id', $user->account_id);
of course im adding an account_id to the users table on every signup.. regrading the facade i didnt change anything in it just required it and started using it rite away

Answer (score 3):

Everything is possible, but I think it's a really bad idea. I never seen anything similar, even in big data projects. I really think you should rethink your DB architecture.

Comment: the idea is i want to keep the data isolated. i dont want users A data to be in the same table as users B data

Comment: Well, noone of your users should have access to any DB anyway. Onbnly your app should have access to DB and separate DBs will not add any security.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is Software as a Service (SaaS). There are a few sites that use this DB model. Like you say yourself the best thing is that you keep your data seperate. I've tried this myself in Symfony2 and it's definately possible, I think it will be possible in Laravel then too.

You will need a script to make a new database when somebody signs up. In Symfony2 I know you can have 2 entity managers so you can always stay connected to your main database and then connect with the client database with the other one. You'll have to store the database information of each user in your main database.

All in all it takes a lot of work to get it to work properly. I don't think it reduces performance, might even enhance it because you don't have all data in one huge DB. If the client information is really delicate most clients will specifically ask for this. If it's not that delicate maybe just look into multi-tenant.

Comment: thanx for the reply.. but im using laravel.. i didnt find anything related to laravel thats why i am asking.. however i will just go with the multi-tenant for now

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should create new database for every user signup rather than u shall create a normalized database with references to a primary table such as users table and fetch particular information of user accordingly.

You should re-design your DB Architecture..

Comment: my architecture is fine and all works well and multi-tenant solves the issue for me.. i just wanna consider other options and see which is more secure and more effective performance wise,  considering every user have limitless amount of entries

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a strange idea.Normally it's better to have a single database for your application.How about creating multiple tables instead of multiple databases?You can create separate tables for users.Think that's a good approach.Furthermore if you need more security, you can allocate a hash key to specific users and when those keys match with relevant user,then the user can access that specific table.